# How to set PYTHONPATH in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

I tried to run a .py file by typing `python twitterstream.py > output.txt` in the command prompt of windows 10. It then said

```
fatal python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123 raise CodecRegistryError,\
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From what I saw through a google search, the solution may be to change the `PYTHONPATH` env variable. However, I had `PYTHONPATH` set to `C:\Python27` for both the user and system variables, but I still get the same error in the command prompt

I also read http://bugs.python.org/issue11288, and tried to change all `PYTHONPATH` system variable which originally pointed to `C:\Python27` and changed it to `C:\Python34` but that didn't solve the problem

I then followed https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows, but when I type `py` it says `Python 2.7.9 ..`, but for `py -3` I get a popup saying `python.exe has stopped working` and

```
 fatal python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123 raise CodecRegistryError,\
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

also, `py hello.py` says `from python 2.7.9 ...`, but changing `#! python` to `#! python3` gives the same error I said before

Even if I set `PATH` AND `PYTHONPATH` user variables to `C:\Python34;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python34\Scripts`, along with the `PythonPath` system variable to `C:\Python34;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python34\Scripts`, but the error was the same as before

Comment: It seems you have `PYTHONHOME` set to `C:\Python27`. Generally there's no reason to set either `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME`, not with the official Python distributions. Unset these variables. There are better ways to manage `sys.path` for a particular installation that don't cause such conflicts.

Comment: i don't see `PYTHONHOME` as an environment variable. And when you say unset, you mean delete them? When I tried that on `PYTHONPATH`, I got the same error as before

Comment: I can reproduce the error if I first enter `set "PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27"`. This overrides Python's default `sys.prefix`, by which it finds its standard library. Python 3 obviously can't use Python 2's standard library. In the command prompt enter `set PYTHON`. Does this list `PYTHONHOME` or just `PYTHONPATH`? If it's just `PYTHONPATH`, that should not cause that error when running `py -3`. Something else is wrong.

Comment: when I enter `set PYTHON` it says `Environment variable PYTHON not defined`

Comment: That means neither `PYTHONHOME` nor `PYTHONPATH` is set. In that command prompt do you get the error for `py -3`?

Comment: no, theres no error anymore when I type `py -3`. I guess changing the `path` user variable to `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;` and then restarting helped. However, when I type `twitterstream.py > output.txt`, I don't get the error message anymore. However, I don't think it worked properly because there should be some content in `output.txt`, but it is still blank. The full code is: https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/blob/master/assignment1/twitterstream.py. So this is using Py2?

Comment: Yes, that's obviously Python  2 code, since it's using `print` as a statement instead of as a function, and `urllib2` isn't in Python 3's standard library. To ensure it runs with Python 2, add the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python2` on the first line.

Comment: I added that shebang and ran `twitterstream.py > output.txt`, but `output.txt` is still empty

Comment: Create a simple test.py that executes `import sys; print(sys.executable)` and run it as `test.py > test.txt`.

Comment: I tried that, but `test.txt` is empty

Comment: Try `C:\Python27\python.exe test.py > test27.txt` and `C:\Python34\python.exe test.py > test34.txt`.

Comment: the output for `test27.txt` is `C:\Python27\python.exe` and `test34.txt` output is `C:\Python34\python.exe`

Comment: What's the output of `assoc .py`?

Comment: Normally .py files are associated with `Python.File`, a progid that's created by Python's installer. Python 3, when installed for all users, sets this to run `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`, which you can check by entering `ftype Python.File`. In your case, check `ftype PyCharmCE40` to see how your system is configured to run .py files. Note that your per-user setting can be different and will override this system setting.

Comment: I don't know why its set to PyCharm. I don't even use PyCharm as I use Ninja instead. Would un-installing it help? Anyway, `ftype PyCharmCE40` gives `PyCharmCE40=C:\ProgramFiles(X86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.5\bin\pycharm.exe "%1"` and `ftype Python.File` gives `Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*`

Comment: Assuming you don't have per-user settings that override this, you should be able to switch to using the py launcher by running `assoc` and `ftype` in an administrator command prompt. First, what's the output of `where py.exe`?

Comment: the output is `c:\windows\py.exe`

Comment: Good, that's the default for an all-users installation. Enter `assoc .py=Python.File` and then `ftype Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`. That should set things right.

Comment: For the first one, I got `access is denied. error occurred while processing .py`. And I got a similar error for your second command

Comment: You need to use an administrator command prompt.

Comment: ok, that works now. However, `twitterstream.py > output.txt` still leaves `output.txt` as empty

Comment: What do you get for `test.py > test.txt`?

Comment: You checked that `assoc .py` and `ftype Python.File` are now correct? If so you probably have a per-user setting that's overriding the system setting. Check Control Panel => Default Programs => Set Association, and try to change .py to use "Python File".

Comment: I don't understand how to do that. In `Set Associations` I see `.py` has a description of `PY File` and Ninja is the current default. I don't see how I can change it to "Python File". Unless you mean have Python Launcher for Windows open it instead of ninja?

Comment: Yes, you configured `Python.File` to open with the py.exe (Python Launcher for Windows); just change your per-user setting to the same.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason by typing only the "py" file name in the command prompt it worked for me. So I typed myScript.py  and it ran correctly. Before this I typed "python myScript.py" and it produced the same error that you experienced. I have the environment variables set `PYTHONPATH=c:\python27` and `PYTHONHOME=c:\python27`. I hope this helps.

Comment: On Windows, `py` is the Python Launcher. This is specific tool for Windows made and shipped with Windows installers to find and use different versions of Python. Linux uses shebangs to tell the OS what program to use to run a file whereas Windows uses file extensions (this is why in Linux you don't always need a file extension). The launcher helps overcome portability issues when developing code for Linux and Windows (more info is in PEP397). Typing just `python` for you executes `C:\python27\python.exe` because you added it to your path.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your program include the line

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Windows will use this to run your code in Python 3.4 rather than 2.7

Comment: but even if I try that on `twitterstream.py`, I get the same error. I also got that error for `hello.py` as explained in that python documentation page I linked to

Comment: don't run it as python twitterstream.py, just run twitterstream.py from the command prompt and it should launch python3 instead of the default 2.7

Comment: ok with that, I don't get the error message anymore. However, I don't think it worked properly because there should be some content in `output.txt`, but it is still blank. The code for `twitterstream.py` is https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/blob/master/assignment1/twitterstream.py

Comment: do you get the correct output without piping output to your text file?  Windows tends to leave the output file empty until the process finishes, so if it takes a long time it can look like its failed (esp if running from task schedular)

Comment: when I run `twitterstream.py` in Ninja, in the output I see some HTML content, which I assume is the correct output. However, `output.txt` is still empty

Comment: try running it from a windows command prompt to confirm you get the output. Then, still in command prompt, run to output.txt. Then try it in Ninja

Comment: running just `twitterstream.py` in the command prompt, I get no output or anything in the prompt. Could the problem be because I probably have a per-user setting that's overriding the system setting and I need to change .py to use "Python File"?

Comment: possibly - I assumed python3.4 was installed ok - maybe check that first with a simple program and make sure the output gets piped ok.